# Powershell Exception issue

Tags: powershell, try-catch

Thank you in advance to taking in consideration such stupid query.
I am trying to get Process list with some extended properties from powershell with following query:

```
**Get-Process -FileVersionInfo | select -Unique | Select-Object * | Format-Table -Property OriginalFilename, FileName, InternalName, ProductName, CompanyName, FileVersion -Wrap > C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\final.txt**
```

It works but for some processes I am unable to get FileVersion which is ok and I don't care about that. Problem is that Even trying to catch the exception, It simple does nothing.

> Get-Process: Cannot enumerate the file version information of the
> "csrss" process. At line:1 char:7
>
> - try { Get-Process -FileVersionInfo | select -Unique | Select-Object * ...
> - ```
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnostics.Process (csrss):Process) [Get-Process],
>     ProcessCommandException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldnotEnumerateFileVer,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

**Tried to get exception details with**

```
**$Error[0] | Select-Property ***
```

and

```
**$Error[0].exception.GetType().fullname**
```

**Which gives following result:**

> WriteErrorStream      : True PSMessageDetails      : Exception
> : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException: Cannot
> enumerate the file version information of the "Idle"
> process. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unable to enumerate the process
> modules.
> at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId,
> Boolean firstModuleOnly)
> at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32
> processId)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
> at System.Management.Automation.PsUtils.GetMainModule(Process
> targetProcess)
> at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand.ProcessRecord()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- TargetObject          : System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle) CategoryInfo
> : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle):Process)
> [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CouldnotEnumerateFileVer,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
> ErrorDetails          : InvocationInfo        :
> System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo ScriptStackTrace      : at
> , : line 1 PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1, 64,
> 0...}

**While trying to catch the exception with [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] it simply does nothing and still throws bunch on red lines.**

```
try { Get-Process -FileVersionInfo | select -Unique | Select-Object * | Format-Table -Property OriginalFilename, FileName, InternalName, ProductName, CompanyName, FileVersion -Wrap > C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\final.txt 
} catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] { 
Write-Verbose "Catch all" -Verbose
}
```

Could you help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `-ErrorAction Stop` in try block!

Comment: Hi @AbdulNiyasPM , thank for the reply. What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the processes you don't have the required access to by adding an ErrorAction to Get-Process

```
Get-Process -FileVersionInfo -ErrorAction Ignore
```

If you somehow do need to know what processes gave you errors, you can use

```
Get-Process -FileVersionInfo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

and look at `$error` afterwards or <sub>cudo's to @zett42</sub>

```
Get-Process -FileVersionInfo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcError
```

and look at `$ProcError` afterwards

Comment: @zett42 - thx, updated